# dist folder generated using grunt build not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, build, gruntjs

I am working on an angular application created using yeoman and using grunt and bower task execution and dependency management respectively.

Application runs fine when i run the application using **grunt serve** but i when i try to run application for deployment using grunt serve:dist then I am getting this error on console:-

> http://localhost:9000/dist/views/pages/login.html  404 not found

and it goes into infinite loop.  I have also attached browser console screenshot here[image: Firefox Console error]

Can someone guide me as what could be the error or where to start for debugging as I am pretty new to angular, bower, grunt and node.

Please let me know if anything else is needed

**grunt serve --verbose output**

```
E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal>grunt serve --verbose Initializing Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks. Initializing config...OK Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ build, default, serve, server, test

Running tasks: serve

Running "serve" task

Loading "grunt-contrib-clean" plugin

Registering "E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal\node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean\tasks" tasks. Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
+ clean

Running "clean:server" (clean) task Verifying property clean.server exists in config...OK Files: .tmp -> server Options: force=false, no-write=false Cleaning .tmp...
>> 1 path cleaned.

Loading "grunt-wiredep" plugin

Registering "E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal\node_modules\grunt-wiredep\tasks" tasks. Loading "wiredep.js" tasks...OK
+ wiredep

Running "wiredep" task

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task Verifying property wiredep.app exists in config...OK Files: scfs/index.html Verifying property wiredep.app.src exists in config...OK Options: src=["scfs/index.html"], ignorePath={}

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task Verifying property wiredep.test exists in config...OK Files: test/karma.conf.js Verifying property wiredep.test.src exists in config...OK Options: devDependencies, src="test/karma.conf.js", ignorePath={}, fileTypes={"js":{"block":{},"detect":{"js":{}},"replace":{"js":"'{{filePath}}',"}}}

Loading "grunt-concurrent" plugin

Registering "E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal\node_modules\grunt-concurrent\tasks" tasks. Loading "concurrent.js" tasks...OK
+ concurrent

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task Verifying property concurrent.server exists in config...OK Files: [no src] -> server Options: limit=8

Initializing Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks. Initializing config...OK Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ build, default, serve, server, test

Running tasks: copy:styles

Loading "grunt-contrib-copy" plugin

Registering "E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal\node_modules\grunt-contrib-copy\tasks" tasks. Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
+ copy

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task Verifying property copy.styles exists in config...OK Files: scfs/styles/main.css -> .tmp/styles/main.css Files: scfs/styles/sb-admin-2.css -> .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css Files: scfs/styles/timeline.css -> .tmp/styles/timeline.css Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], timestamp=false, mode=false Copying scfs/styles/main.css -> .tmp/styles/main.css Reading scfs/styles/main.css...OK Writing .tmp/styles/main.css...OK Copying scfs/styles/sb-admin-2.css -> .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css Reading scfs/styles/sb-admin-2.css...OK Writing .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css...OK Copying scfs/styles/timeline.css -> .tmp/styles/timeline.css Reading scfs/styles/timeline.css...OK Writing .tmp/styles/timeline.css...OK Copied 3 files

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2016-01-28 13:01:14 UTC) loading tasks               318ms  ¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦ 45% loading grunt-contrib-copy  301ms  ¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦ 43% copy:styles                  83ms  ¦¦¦¦¦ 12% Total 703ms

Loading "grunt-postcss" plugin

Registering "E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal\node_modules\grunt-postcss\tasks" tasks. Loading "postcss.js" tasks...OK
+ postcss

Running "postcss:server" (postcss) task Verifying property postcss.server exists in config...OK Files: .tmp/styles/main.css -> .tmp/styles/main.css Files: .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css -> .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css Files: .tmp/styles/timeline.css -> .tmp/styles/timeline.css Options: processors=[null], map, diff=false, safe=false Reading .tmp/styles/main.css...OK Reading .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css...OK Reading .tmp/styles/timeline.css...OK Writing .tmp/styles/main.css...OK File .tmp/styles/main.css created. Writing .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css...OK File .tmp/styles/sb-admin-2.css created. Writing .tmp/styles/timeline.css...OK File .tmp/styles/timeline.css created.
>> 3 processed stylesheets created.

Loading "grunt-contrib-connect" plugin

Registering "E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal\node_modules\grunt-contrib-connect\tasks" tasks. Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
+ connect

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task Verifying property connect.livereload exists in config...OK File: [no files] Options: protocol="http", port=9000, hostname="localhost", base=".", directory=null, keepalive=false, debug=false, livereload=35729, open, useAvailablePort=false, onCreateServer=null, middleware=undefined Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000

Loading "grunt-contrib-watch" plugin

Registering "E:\workspaces\scfs\sentinal\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\tasks" tasks. Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Running "watch" task Waiting... Verifying property watch exists in config...OK Verifying property watch.bower.files exists in config...OK Verifying property watch.js.files exists in config...OK Verifying property watch.jsTest.files exists in config...OK Verifying property watch.styles.files exists in config...OK Verifying property watch.gruntfile.files exists in config...OK Verifying property watch.livereload.files exists in config...OK Live reload server started on port: 35729 Watching bower.json for changes. Watching .tmp for changes. Watching bower_components for changes. Watching dist for changes. Watching node_modules for changes. Watching scfs for changes. Watching test for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\app.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\controllers for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\directives for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\services for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\shared for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\app1.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\constants.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\controllers\chartContoller.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\controllers\dashboard for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\controllers\user for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\controllers\form.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\controllers\login.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\services\auth.resolver.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\services\authentication.service.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\services\datatable.service.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\services\map.service.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\services\user.service.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\shared\flash.service.js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts\shared\session.js for changes. Watching test\spec\controllers\about.js for changes. Watching test\spec\controllers\main.js for changes. Watching scfs\styles\main.css for changes. Watching scfs\styles\sb-admin-2.css for changes. Watching scfs\styles\timeline.css for changes. Watching Gruntfile.js for changes. Watching .tmp for changes. Watching bower_components for changes. Watching dist for changes. Watching node_modules for changes. Watching scfs for changes. Watching test for changes. Watching scfs\404.html for changes. Watching scfs\bower_components for changes. Watching scfs\images for changes. Watching scfs\js for changes. Watching scfs\scripts for changes. Watching scfs\styles for changes. Watching scfs\views for changes. Watching scfs\index.html for changes. Watching scfs\views\chart.html for changes. Watching scfs\views\dashboard for changes. Watching scfs\views\drivers for changes. Watching scfs\views\pages for changes. Watching scfs\views\settings for changes. Watching scfs\views\ui-elements for changes. Watching scfs\views\unit for changes. Watching scfs\views\user for changes. Watching scfs\views\userType for changes. Watching scfs\views\vehicle for changes. Watching scfs\views\form.html for changes.
```

**GruntFile.js connect config:-**

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect.static('test'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try running `grunt serve --verbose` and post here the result of the command. Did you check that the `dist`directory contains all it should ?

Comment: Added the verbose output and yes directory contains all the that is required if I am not wrong the build concatenates the html files so they are are not there in directory

Comment: In the console logs, the URL contains the scfs directory. I'm not sure it should be here. Can you post your config for the task 'connect' ?

Comment: I renamed default app directory that generated using yo to scfs and also changed the appConfig.app variable value to scfs in grunt js and appPath in bower.json as well.

Comment: Also, the project runs fine when grunt:serve but the dist folder that gets generated using grunt build doesn't run properly

Comment: But when you use grunt build and try to run what's generated in the dist folder, which server runs it ? Which server are you calling with "localhost" ? I think I don't understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: I am only generating the dist folder for production. And When i generate it using grunt build and run on web server then i get above error in JS console where as running same code in dev environment works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute just **grunt** command, without anything

Comment: It run jshint task with some warnings like this:-                
scfs/scripts/services/user.service.js
  line 11  col 25  'UserService' was used before it was defined.
  line 27  col 9   Inner functions should be listed at the top of the outer function.
  line 27  col 24  'GetAll' was used before it was defined.
  line 31  col 25  'GetById' was used before it was defined.
  line 35  col 31  'GetByUsername' was used before it was defined.
  line 39  col 24  'Create' was used before it was defined.
  line 43  col 24  'Update' was used before it was defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to figure out the issues. Actully whenever there is an error in javascript code the **$templateCache** ,that holds all the html templates, doesn't gets populated. AS I was using chrome and due to live reload of application I was not able to veiwe the original error as the conitnuous hitting of login.html html page makes the Chrome browser unresposive and orginal error falls back in the javascript console log.

Now when I ran dist folder build in firefox I was able to see the error for few second before it also falls back here. On resolving that error the app worked fine.

And the error actually was issue with dependency injection which wasn't done properly in one of my service files which during **grunt build** minification task doesn't gets interpreted properly and gives error during start of application.

Hope this helps someone!!